# Web Service Auto Generated Files

Tags: java, web-services, soap, service, web

When I create a new Web service using RSA 7.5 IDE and Web Sphere 7.0 server from a Web Application, then I can see a few auto-generated files created by this process, namely:

1) For the service, a SEI file is created

2) For the models, ser, deser and helper files are created.

But I cant understand what are the use of all these SEI, ser, deser and helper files.

Any valid explanation on this will be much appreciated.

BOUNTY EDIT:

**Bounty-Edit:**

Since I did not get any response I would like to ask this question again - offering a bounty to encourage an in-depth answer. I would love to know how and when are these files used internally?

Regards,

Comment: If I were you I would firstly implement web service with more common IDE and server like NetBeans and GlassFish. So I could have lots of tutorial to follow. Then move to the your IDE and server :)

Comment: Can you provide some inputs on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files are related to the WebSphere mapping between Java, WSDL, and XML. They are automatically generated, and should not need to be edited. You should pretend they are not there (except if they are not there you may have trouble deploying...).

- SEI - Service Endpoint Interface
- ser - Serialize
- deser - Deserialize
- helper - ?

Here are some psuedo-helpful links, that may provide some more insight into your question:

- [IBM Technotes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21289115)
- [WebSphere v6.1 Handbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247257/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) (check Chapter 15 -> Creating a Web Service --> Generated Files)

Comment: need of the ser and deser files? Any info on that?

Answer (score 6):

**Service Endpoint Interface (SEI):**

> SEI is the Java interface corresponding to the Web service port type
>   being implemented. It is defined by the JAX-RPC, which specifies the
>   language mapping from WSDL 1.1 to Java. [Ref](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.webservice.was.creation.ui.doc/concepts/cwebsptover.html)
>
> Or
>
> A service endpoint interface (**SEI**) is a Java interface that
>   declares the methods that a client can invoke on the service. [Ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC3.html)

These `ser`,`dser`,`helper` are helpers to convert an XML document into a java object and vice versa (WebServices). [Ref](http://websphere.sys-con.com/node/43345)

**Files generated in the server project:** ([WebSphere Application Server 6.1 Ref](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247257/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm))

According to the settings made during the run of the wizard, the following files in the `WeatherJavaBeanWeb` project have been created:

**Service endpoint interface (SEI):** `itso.bean.WeatherJavaBean_SEI.java` is the interface defining the methods exposed in the Web service.

**WSDL file:** `/WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/WeatherJavaBean.wsdl` describes the Web service.

**Deployment descriptor:** `webservices.xml`, `ibm-webservices-ext.xml` and `ibm-webservices-bnd.xml`. These files describe the Web service according to the Web services for `J2EE` style (`JSR 109`). The `JAX-RPC` mapping is described in the `WeatherJavaBean_mapping.xml` file.

**Data mapping files:** The helper beans in the itso.objects package perform the data conversion from XML to Java objects and back.

A servlet is defined in the Web deployment descriptor to invoke the JavaBean.

[image]

Hope this information help you.

Answer (score 2):

All these files are basically generated for webservice.

A web service ia basically a port between 2 running applications independant of the framework or language.

Leta say if you are using java from one side of web service then for complete compilation the java end would need some class files that have those methids which you wish to call on the service.

For this a stub is generated. This stub is basically an interface(SEI).

Also websphere needs additional files for implementing the webservices functionality, thus tge helper files.

This is basically the summary of it.